# Tailwind is not being added on my reactjs project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am following the official `Tailwind CSS` installation for `reactjs` tutorial step-by-step but `tailwindcss`  is not being added on my `reactjs` project.

This is the [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) to the tutorial I am following,

I think the only part where I might have a mistake is the `tailwind.config.js` file and here it is.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

postcss.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Comment: Please share your index.css file and the output you see when running ```npm run start```.

Comment: @tomerpacific just added index.css to the main post and when I run `npm run start` I do not get any error, just the regular messages.

Comment: tailwind documentation on reactjs does not have anything on postcss.config.js, this file on my project is empty.

Comment: Are you using CRA version 5 and did you restart CRA after the changes were made?

Comment: I just updated it to version 5 and now get the error of `Error: Cannot find module 'workbox-build/build/options/schema/webpack-generate-sw'` even after I install the webpack thing still same error

Comment: How do I initiate installations of your project? Could you show us the pacakge.json and folder&file structure of your project ?

Comment: Could you provide Your code snippet with how you use tailwindcss in your react app ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

1. Update your react-scripts package v4 to v5 via `npm install react-scripts@latest` or `yarn add react-scripts@latest`
2. Stop your React app and run again